# Show 0 even if there is no row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I create this query

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN (c.designation <> '') THEN UPPER(c.designation) 
        ELSE 'CATEGORIE INCONNU' 
    END AS designation,
    CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(lg) > 0  THEN SUM (lg.montant_categorie_maintenance) 
        ELSE 0 
    END AS valeur
FROM sch_gparc.maint_categorie_maintenance c 
LEFT JOIN sch_gparc.maint_lg_categorie_maintenance lg
    ON lg.id_categorie = c.id
LEFT JOIN sch_gparc.maint_maintenance m
    ON lg.id_maintenance = m.id 
WHERE EXTRACT( MONTH FROM m.date_fin::DATE) = EXTRACT( MONTH FROM '01/04/2017'::DATE)
    AND EXTRACT( YEAR FROM m.date_fin::DATE) = EXTRACT( YEAR FROM '01/04/2017'::DATE)
    AND m.type_maintenance = 'PREVENTIVE'
GROUP BY c.designation
```

The goal of this query is to show all the `c.designation` and if there is no record show a `0`.

the problem is : It doesn't show anything (case there's no record when i perform the left join).

**EDIT** : The desired data

```
| designation    |   value       |
|    MOTEUR      |     0         |
|    DIVERS      |     0         |
```

What is show now : nothing.

Comment: Be careful not to restrict left-joined tables in WHERE with NULL-prohibiting predicates. This way you turn LEFT JOIN to INNER. Move `EXTRACT( MONTH FROM m.date_fin::DATE) = EXTRACT( MONTH FROM '01/04/2017'::DATE)` to `ON`

Comment: @Serg the problem with moving the conditions from `WHERE` to `ON` is to lost the good behaviour of the query that's mean the query will show wrong result

Comment: Does it mean you need INNER JOIN really? Then it's quite OK to return no rows.

Comment: Add sample data and a desired output to clarify the subject.

Answer (score 0):

The "problem" is that when you group, you lose the rows that don't have anything to group.

I usually just left join the aggregated query back to the table from which I first selected.

```
SELECT
    s.designation,
    COALESCE(s.valeur, 0) -- coalesce the NULL rows to zero
FROM sch_gparc.maint_categorie_maintenance cat
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        c.id,
        CASE
            WHEN (c.designation <> '') THEN UPPER(c.designation)
            ELSE 'CATEGORIE INCONNU'
        END AS designation,
        SUM (lg.montant_categorie_maintenance) AS valeur
    FROM sch_gparc.maint_categorie_maintenance c
    LEFT JOIN sch_gparc.maint_lg_categorie_maintenance lg
        ON lg.id_categorie = c.id
    LEFT JOIN sch_gparc.maint_maintenance m
        ON (
            lg.id_maintenance = m.id
            AND EXTRACT( MONTH FROM m.date_fin::DATE) = EXTRACT( MONTH FROM '01/04/2017'::DATE)
            AND EXTRACT( YEAR FROM m.date_fin::DATE) = EXTRACT( YEAR FROM '01/04/2017'::DATE)
            AND m.type_maintenance = 'PREVENTIVE'
        )
    GROUP BY c.designation
) s ON (s.id = cat.id)
```

Comment: The result that is give is inccorect ( when you use the condition  `m.type_maintenance = 'PREVENTIVE'` ) the result must be 0 in every row

Comment: Well, with no test data it's quite difficult to produce working queries. How was the result incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the following one and it's working :

```
select c.designation , coalesce(gm.valeur,0) as valeur  
from sch_gparc.maint_categorie_maintenance c 
left join (SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN (c.designation <> '') THEN UPPER(c.designation) 
        ELSE 'CATEGORIE INCONNU' 
    END AS designation,
    CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(m.id) > 0  THEN SUM (lg.montant_categorie_maintenance) 
        ELSE 0 
    END AS valeur
FROM sch_gparc.maint_categorie_maintenance c 
LEFT JOIN sch_gparc.maint_lg_categorie_maintenance lg
    ON lg.id_categorie = c.id
LEFT JOIN sch_gparc.maint_maintenance m
    ON lg.id_maintenance = m.id 

WHERE 
(EXTRACT( MONTH FROM m.date_fin::DATE) = EXTRACT( MONTH FROM '01/05/2017'::DATE)
    AND EXTRACT( YEAR FROM m.date_fin::DATE) = EXTRACT( YEAR FROM '01/05/2017'::DATE)
    AND m.type_maintenance = 'PREVENTIVE') or m.id is null
GROUP BY 1)gm on gm.designation = UPPER(c.designation)
```

Hope that helped you.

Comment: Thank you very much